# Linking Credit Card and Debit Card classes to a Bank Account Class

Tags: java, class, oop, credit-card

I'm learning Java, and one of my assignments is to create Credit and Debit Cards classes so that you can create new cards linked to a new individual account when one is created. The credit card should store purchases, and when the user makes a payment (total or partial), substract the amount from the account (plus 3% interest). The debit card immediately substracts the purchase's amount from the account.

I have written everything and made it work, but only as nested classes within the Account class. Is there a way to have Account, Credit and Debit as three separate classes and make it so that every time that you create a new account, you can optionally create cards linked to each new individual account?

Disclaimer: I'm trimming some of the code because it's all in spanish so I don't have to translate it all (mainly booleans to check for positive amounts and stuff like that), but the code is still functional. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
package accounts;

public class Account {

    protected static double balance;
    protected static String accountNumber;

    public Account() {
    }

    public Account(String accountNumber, double balance) {
        Account.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        Account.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void deposit(double depositAmount) {
            Account.balance += depositAmount;
        }

    public void extraction(double extractionAmount) {
            Account.balance -= extractionAmount;
        }

    public void showBalance() {
        System.out.println("Your current balance is: " + getBalance());
    }

    protected static class DebitCard {

        private String userName;
        private int cardNumber;

        public DebitCard () {
        }

        public DebitCard (String userName, int cardNumber) {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public int getCardNumber() {
            return cardNumber;
        }

        public void debitPurchase(double purchaseAmount) {
                Account.balance -= purchaseAmount;
            }
    }

    protected static class CreditCard {

        private String userName;
        private int cardNumber;
        private double creditCardDebt;
        private double limit;

        public CreditCard () {
        }

        public CreditCard(String userName, int cardNumber, double limit) {
            this.userName = userName;
            this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
            this.limit = limit;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public int getCardNumber() {
            return cardNumber;
        }

        public double getLimit() {
            return limit;
        }

        public double getCrediCardDebt() {
            return creditCardDebt;
        }

        public void creditCardPurchase(double purchaseAmount) {
            if (this.creditCardDebt + purchaseAmount > this.limit) {
                Error notEnoughLimit = new Error("There's not enough limit to make this purchase");
                throw notEnoughLimit ;
            } else {
                this.creditCardDebt += purchaseAmount + (purchaseAmount * 0.03);
                this.limit -= purchaseAmount;
                this.creditCardDebt += purchaseAmount + (purchaseAmount* 0.03);
                this.limit -= purchaseAmount;
            }
         }

        public void payCard(double payAmount) {
            Account.balance -= payAmount;
            this.creditCardDebt = this.creditCardDebt - payAmount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have some issue here
    protected static String accountNumber; \\ that mean there will be only one single accountNumber for all objects of type account (mean all accounts will have the same accountNUmber ) same issue with balance but if that what you want then it's ok

you can create the other class as public class but you would need  away to link them with the account so maybe you add object of type account to them also 

Account owner; as filed to both of those classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  But before you do that, you should solve the problem caused by declaring `balance` and `accountNumber` as `static` variables.  By doing that, you have made every `Account` instance share one account number and one balance.

Those variables should also be `private` so that other classes can't access or change them directly.

Once you have fixed that, you should then change the constructors for `Credit` and `Debit` to take an *instance* of `Account` as a parameter.  They store this in a private field, and then perform operations to add and remove money from the `Account` ... via operations on the `Account` object.

Comment: Thank you! That did it :).